# NSAccessibilityProtocol vs NSAccessibility (keep XCode 9 & 10 compatibility)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

I've just installed Xcode 10 beta.

The problem is:

- XCode 10 wants me to change NSAccessibility to NSAccessibilityProtocol
- XCode 9 knows nothing about [NSAccessibilityProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityprotocol?changes=latest_minor)

The error message in XCode 10 is

> 'NSAccessibility' is unavailable in Swift: has been renamed to
>   'NSAccessibilityProtocol'

The error message in XCode 9 is

> Use of undeclared type 'NSAccessibilityProtocol'

Is there a way to keep project compatible with both XCode version?

I tried:

```
#if swift(>=4.1)
return object is NSAccessibilityProtocol
#else
return object is NSAccessibility
#endif
```

But it haven't helped.

If I'm not mistaken, Swift version is the same for both XCodes and it depends on "Build Settings" in current context. But I tried at least.

I read [compatibility article](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/Compatibility.html), but at the moment there are very few tips.

**Looks like it depends on AppKit version. But I don't know how to express such condition.**

[What's new in AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10_14?language=objc):

> **Swift and Objective-C API Enhancements AppKit's Swift interface is**
>
> improved in macOS 10.14 in pursuit of greater clarity, consistency,
>   concision, and a native Swift feel. In many cases, these enhancements
>   go in hand with refinements to the corresponding Objective-C APIs. The
>   changes include formalizing informal protocols; moving enumerations to
>   a common-prefix identifier convention; hoisting Swift declarations
>   into appropriate local namespaces; renaming some functions for Swift;
>   replacing functions with computed properties; adding setters for some
>   previously read-only array-valued properties; and similar enhancements
>   that are discussed in these release notes.